# nuxt-link makes different urls in development and generate/production mode

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-link

I have created a nuxt project and in development mode It works fine, but when I run `npm run generate` or host it on a server, links generated by nuxt-link haven't correct href value. For example this is the address that generated in development mode:

```html
<nuxt-link :to="{name: 'lang-music', params: {lang: key, music: song.name}}"></nuxt-link>
```

```
http://localhost:3000/yiddish/Die%20goldene%20Pave
```

But on gitlab pages it generate:

```
https://username.gitlab.io/yiddish/Die%20goldene%20Pave
```

While it should be:

```
https://username.gitlab.io/learnlyric/yiddish/Die%20goldene%20Pave
```

My pages folder structure:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is Nuxt doesn't know your base url, you just need to add it to the `nuxt.config.js` file.

```js
// nuxt.config.js

export default {
  router: {
    base: process.env.DEPLOY_ENV === 'GH_PAGES' ? '/learnlyric' : '';
  }
}
```

See the [Nuxt documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/#base) for more details.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why your code not working but `base: '/learnlyric'` solved the problem.

Comment: It uses the `DEPLOY_ENV` variable that you can set while executing a command. For example `generate:gh-pages": "DEPLOY_ENV=GH_PAGES nuxt generate` (doesn't work on Windows, see [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) for this). If you only have one deployment environment, you can use `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'` instead! If the answer suits you, could you flag it with the green check, thanks 